# Google Apps: MX records for zonefile

Tags: email, google, domain-name-system, gmail

I have a question about using Google Apps for handling emails.
I don't want to set up a whole entire mail system on my server, so I decided to use Google Apps. The ownership of my domain is approved, and now I'm trying to change the MX records in the zone file of my domain. But I think I'm doing wrong, it doesn't work.

I want to use mail.mydomain.com as a adress to the mail server for POP, SMTP and IMAP. My zone file looks like this:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA ns1.first-ns.de. postmaster.robot.first-ns.de. (
    2011011700   ; serial
    14400        ; refresh
    1800         ; retry
    604800       ; expire
    86400 )      ; minimum

@                        IN NS      robotns3.second-ns.com.
@                        IN NS      robotns2.second-ns.de.
@                        IN NS      ns1.first-ns.de.

@                        IN A       111.111.111.111
localhost                IN A       127.0.0.1
www                      IN A       111.111.111.111
ftp                      IN CNAME   www
loopback                 IN CNAME   localhost
mail                     IN CNAME   @
relay                    IN CNAME   www
@                        IN MX 10   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@                        IN MX 10   ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@                        IN MX 10   ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@                        IN MX 10   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@                        IN MX 10   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

I hope someone can figure out, what's wrong with this configuration. When I start a ping on mail.mydomain.org I get an answer from 111.111.111.111 and not from the google server ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

thx,
tux

Comment: Did you give it time to propogate the DNS changes?  Sometimes it can take up to 24 hours.

Comment: Bah! DNS doesn't propagate.

Answer (score 1):

mail.mydomain.org will have to be defined in the DNS system somewhere.

With your current setup, any service looking for the email exchange service ('MX') for your domain, will first try the MX string with the lowest value, i.e.:

```
MX 10   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
```

In other words: you either don't need to worry about having a 'mail.mydomain.org', or
you have to define 'mail.mydomain.org' in your DNS settings

Also, to investigate the MX setup of a domain.com, you can do:

```
nslookup -type=MX domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're checking the MX records? Try an MX lookup tool like this:

http://www.mxtoolbox.com/

Also, shouldn't your mail CNAME record point to ghs.google.com?

If you don't want to use mxtoolbox you can use nslookup:

> Go to a command prompt and type "CMD"
>
> and press enter
>
> Type "NSLOOKUP" and press enter
> Type "set type=mx"
>
> press enter

Answer (score 0):

mail.mydomain.com isn't an MX record for your domain.

mail.mydomain.com is a CNAME (alias) for example.com, which is a synthesised &ORIGIN for your domain based on the @ symbol replacement you've created for the A record.

If you want to verify your MX records then you should perform an MX record test using dig or nslookup.